# Why it is called "The Ides of March"?

Tags: title, the-ides-of-march

When I search the words *The Ides of March* it gives me the assassination day of Julius Caesar.

But the movie's plot is related to political drama.

Why it is called "The Ides of March"?

Comment: The assassination of Caesar would be considered political drama, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It's a reference to Shakespeare's *Julius Caesar*.

[This article](http://filmcolossus.com/the-ides-of-march/analysis) offers a thorough analysis:

> *Ides* is a movie adaptation of the play *Farragut North*.  The play ends with Stephen being fired.  The movie, obviously, continues on.  And this is why the title is different.
>
> [...]
>
> The reason the movie is called *The Ides of March* and not *Farragut North* is for the comparison to Shakespeare.  And the comparison to Shakespeare is a reference to the assassination of Caesar.  Do you see how this fits with our movie?
>
> Stephen (Ryan Gosling) is Brutus.  Governor Morris (Clooney) is Julius Caesar.  (Shakespeare's play, as with Clooney's film, casts Brutus as the protagonist).
>
> Brutus betrayed Caesar, so I think we can extrapolate that Stephen betrays Morris.  The clue to this, the title aside, comes as Stephen is, at the end of the movie, sitting in the chair, waiting for the live TV interview to start.  A clip of Morris is playing.  It's a speech about decency, about honor, about doing the right thing.  Morris's words happen to also be the topics on Stephen's mind.  It's a deft touch of irony.  But also foreshadowing.  And elucidation of Stephen's thoughts, which we're never really privy to.

After reading that article, you can find further discussion in [this forum thread](http://www.modigmovie.com/movies-investigated/inquiry-43-explaining-the-end-of-ides-of-march).

---

Interestingly, Clooney had to fight to keep the title *The Ides of March*. From [this article](http://www.slashfilm.com/sony-picks-george-clooneys-the-ides-march-late-2011-oscarquliafying-run):

> Interesting: the trade says Sony wanted to use the play’s title, *Farragut North*, rather than *The Ides of March*, with the reason cited being the  recognizance of the title. But Mr. Clooney won out, and the film will use *The Ides of March* for now.